# not able to parse json array using org.json library?

Tags: java, json, string, org.json

I have a below JSON Array and I am trying to parse it but it is giving me an exception:

```
[{
    "response": {
        "client": "123456",
        "111": {
            "data": "0\u00181535480381\u00191535480347\u0018\"voyager\";-1;12;0\u00181535480075\u00191535480069",
            "time": "981542121421"
        }
    }
}]
```

I am using `org.json.JSONArray` to parse the above JSON but below code throws exception:

```
String json =
    "[{ \"response\": { \"client\": \"123456\", \"111\": { \"data\": \"0\u00181535480381\u00191535480347\u0018\"voyager\";-1;12;0\u00181535480075\u00191535480069\", \"time\": \"981542121421\" } } }]";
 // this line throws exception
 JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);
```

Here is the exception I am seeing:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.json.JSONException: Expected a ',' or '}' at character 81
    at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:410)
    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:222)
    at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:344)
    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:205)
    at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:344)
    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:205)
    at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:344)
    at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:125)
    at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:157)
```

What is wrong I am doing here?

Comment: You have some Unicode characters in the `data` field.  My guess is that this has something to do with that.

Comment: I think this has to do with double quotes string `voyager` inside my json.

Comment: Those quotes are properly escaped though, with backslashes.  You may test this by removing them and see what happens.

Comment: Yes once I remove double quotes around voyager then it works fine without any issues so something is weird.

Comment: Your raw text seems to parse fine for me ([see here](http://json.parser.online.fr)).  I don't know what is wrong.

Comment: yes raw ttext is fine and I validated as well but when we parse using this library then it fails.

Comment: You should also include the exact Java code you used to parse, rather than just the raw string.  I upvoted your question by the way.

Comment: Unable to reproduce. Copy-pasted JSON to text file, then read it and parsed it without error. Assuming `json` is a `String` variable, try printing `json.substring(81)` to see where "character 81" is.

Comment: @Andreas Are you trying to parse using that same library? If you use that same library I am using then it won't work.

Comment: @Andreas edited my question to add code which shows how I am doing?

Comment: @john You didn't specify exactly which library you are using. I'm using [`org.json:json:20090211`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json/20090211)

Comment: The JSON text you show, and the string literal you show, is not the same text. Try printing `json`, and you'll see the difference. Any `"` or ``\`` in the JSON text must be escaped with a ``\`` when inside a Java string literal. E.g. `...7\u0018\"voyager\";..` must be escaped as `...7\\u0018\\\"voyager\\\";..`

Answer (score 3):

Put esacpe charaters around voyager like below.

```
\\\"voyager\\\"
```

I tested it worked.

```
import org.json.JSONArray;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String json = "[{ \"response\": { \"client\": \"123456\", \"111\": { \"data\": \"0\u00181535480381\u00191535480347\u0018\\\"voyager\\\";-1;12;0\u00181535480075\u00191535480069\", \"time\": \"981542121421\" } } }]";
        // this line throws exception
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);
    }
}
```

Since it has already escape characters in JOSN you need to double escape in java to retain them.

Comment: You also need to escape all ``\`` characters, e.g. `\u` becomes `\\u`

Answer (score 2):

\"voyager\"

This needs to be double escaped.  The parser is seeing the `\"` as the end of the quote and expecting `,` or `}`

Try

```
\\\"voyager\\\"
```

Answer (score 1):

> *In JSON syntax, you were wrong one place - "111", because names must be strings. thus, @NarayanP's code would not run on android system.*

Your code throws exception, this is not json's mistake. problems are in assignment line;

```
String json = "...";
```

if you put below value into *json* through http response or file reading

```
"data": "0\u00181535480381\u00191535480347\u0018\"voyager\";-1;12;0\u00181535480075\u00191535480069"
```

then actually json's value will be

```
data: 015354803811535480347"voyager";-1;12;015354800751535480069  [escaped \u0018 etc. by stackoverflow]
```

if the JSON string contains a semicolon then only the part of the string up until the first semicolon encountered was being returned.
thus, while parsing upper json string, data item will be same as

```
015354803811535480347"voyager"
```

Then "-1","12" are JSON syntax errors.

Following is full-code without errors.

```
String json = "[{\n" +
            "    \"response\": {\n" +
            "        \"client\": \"123456\",\n" +
            "        \"varname111\": {\n" +
            "            \"data\": \"0\\u00181535480381\\u00191535480347\\u0018\\\"voyager\\\";-1;12;0\\u00181535480075\\u00191535480069\",\n" +
            "            \"time\": \"981542121421\"\n" +
            "        }\n" +
            "    }\n" +
            "}]";

JSONArray jsonArray = null;

try {
    jsonArray= new JSONArray(json);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```